# SFINAE not solvable overload

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

#### Context

I want to check whether an element is present inside a container or not.

I would like to write a *generic* function which exploits the structure of the container.

In particular, the function should pick the method `count()` for those data structures which support that (e.g., `std::set`, `std::unordered_set`, ...).

In C++17 we can write something like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container, typename Element>
constexpr bool hasElement(const Container& c, const Element& e) {
  if constexpr (hasCount<Container>::value) {
    return c.count(e);
  } else {
    return std::find(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c), e) != std::cend(c);
  }
}
```

---

All right! Now we need to implement `hasCount<T>` *trait*.

With *SFINAE* (and `std::void_t` in C++17) we can write something like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct hasCount: std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct hasCount<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::count)>> : std::true_type {};
```

---

This approach works quite well. For instance, the following snippet compiles (with previous definitions, of course):

```
struct Foo {
  int count();
};

struct Bar {};

static_assert(hasCount<Foo>::value);
static_assert(!hasCount<Bar>::value);
```

---

#### Problem

Of course, I am going to use `hasCount` on *STL* data structure, such as `std::vector`, and `std::set`. Here the problem!

Since C++14, [`std::set<T>::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count) has a template overload.

Therefore `static_assert(hasCount<std::set<int>>::value);` fails!

That's because `decltype(&std::set<int>::count)` cannot be automatically deduced due to the overload.

---

#### Question

Given the context:

- is there a way to solve the automatic overload?
- if not, is there another way to write a better `hasCount` trait? (*C++20 Concepts* are not available).

External dependencies (libraries, such as *boost*) should be avoided.

Comment: `decltype` of an expression that calls the function with a value? i.e. `decltype(declval<T>().count(declval<int>()))`

Comment: anyhow you should require that the container has a method `count` that can be called, not only that it has some member called `count`, if you do that I think the problem will be gone

Comment: @BoBTFish good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to solve the automatic overload?

Yes, if you know the types of the arguments to pass to the method. In your case, if I understand correctly, `Element`.

Your answer show how to solve the problem modifying your original code. Next I propose a solution based on declared-only `constexpr` functions

> is there another way to write a better hasCount trait?

I don't know if better, but usually I prefer use `constexpr` functions.

Something as follows (<s>caution: code not tested</s> [tested](https://godbolt.org/z/lMrZcU) directly from the OP)

```
template <typename...>
constexpr std::false_type hasCountF (...);

template <typename T, typename ... As>
constexpr auto hasCountF (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().count(std::declval<As>()...), std::true_type{});

template <typename ... Ts>
using has_count = decltype(hasCountF<Ts...>(1));
```

and maybe also (only from C++14)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto has_count_v = has_count<Ts...>::value:
```

and you can call it as follows

```
if constexpr ( has_count_v<Container, Element> )
```

In your case, using the `Container` `c` and `Element` `e` in your function, you can make it simpler (avoiding a lot of `std::declval()`'s) and you can try with a couple of functions as follows

```
template <typename...>
constexpr std::false_type hasCountF (...);

template <typename C, typename ... As>
constexpr auto hasCountF (C const & c, As const & ... as)
   -> decltype( c.count(as...), std::true_type{});
```

calling it as follows

```
if constexpr ( decltype(hasCountF(c, e))::value )
```

but I prefer the preceding solution because require more typewriting but is more flexible.

Comment: Cool! [I've tested here](https://godbolt.org/z/lMrZcU). If you want, you can add the code to your answer.

Comment: @BiagioFesta - answer improved... well... not sure it's improved.

Answer (score 1):

From question comment, the right approach is to check the "*call expression*" (rather than the existence of the method).

Therefore, an improvement of the *trait struct* may be the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct hasCount : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct hasCount<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().count(std::declval<U>()))>> : 
  std::true_type {};
```

Given two instance `t` and `u` of types respectively `T` and `U`, it checks whether the expression `t.count(u)` is valid or not.

Therefore the following code is valid:

```
static_assert(hasCount<std::set<int>, int>::value);
```

Solving the problem in the question.

---

#### Additional Notes

The generic algorithm now can be implemented with:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container, typename Element>
constexpr bool hasElement(const Container& c, const Element& e) {
  if constexpr (hasCount<Container, Element>::value) {
    return c.count(e);
  } else {
    return std::find(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c), e) != std::cend(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind it might be more efficient to check for member `find`, rather than member `count`, as count will do more work in a `multi_` container.

Comment: @BoBTFish you say so because `count` should "counts" for *all* keys?

That is: in the case of `mult_` container you cannot limit to "find the first one", but you have to count all of them.

Comment: `hasCount<const Container&, const Element&>::value` is actually what you want to assert

Comment: @BiagioFesta Exactly. Also worth noting that for C++20, it is proposed to [add a `contains` member function to the associative containers](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?search=contains). Not much use to you now of course, but worth knowing.

Comment: @BoBTFish yeah thank you. I was already aware. However, asymptotically, we can still rely on `count`. The worst case implies `multi_` container (which I've never seen in my life in production code) and the case where you have a lot of duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful in places like this to simply defer to a separate overload set that has a fallback:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
constexpr auto hasElement_impl(int, const Container& c, const Element& e) 
    -> decltype(c.count(e))
{
    return c.count(e);
}

template <typename Container, typename Element>
constexpr bool hasElement_impl(long, const Container& c, const Element& e) 
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), e) != c.end();
}

template <typename Container, typename Element>
constexpr bool hasElement(const Container& c, const Element& e) 
{
    return hasElement_impl(0, c, e);
}
```

If you can do `c.count(e)`, do that. Otherwise, fallback to `find()`. You don't need to write a type trait in this case, and indeed the question itself demonstrates the problem with trying to go that route. Much simpler not to.

---

Alternatively, using something like Boost.HOF:

```
constexpr inline auto hasElement = boost::hof::first_of(
    [](auto const& cnt, auto const& elem) BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(cnt.count(elem)),
    [](auto const& cnt, auto const& elem) {
        return std::find(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), elem) != cnt.end();
    }
);
```

---

In C++20, this sort of algorithm refinement will be a lot easier thanks to concepts:

```
template <AssociativeContainer C, typename E>
bool hasElement(const C& c, const E& e) { return c.count(e); }

template <typename C, typename E>
bool hasElement(const C& c, const E& e) { return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), e) != c.end(); }
```